# How to implement negation in Solidity?

Tags: evm, math, bit-manipulation

I know that the EVM uses the [two's complement system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to represent signed values, and that EVM words have 256 bits.

How can I negate a number in Solidity, i.e. obtain its negation under the two's complement?

Answer (score 2):

I'll start with a refresher on how to compute the two's complement of a number: represent it in binary, invert all its bits (i.e., change all 0s to 1s and all 1s to 0s), and then add 1 to the result.

Now, onto how to implement this in Solidity. There are three ways:

1. Using the unary operator `-` in high-level Solidity.
2. Using the bitwise NOT operator `~` in high-level Solidity.
3. Using the `sub` instruction in Yul.

Examples:

```
function twosComplementUnary(int256 x) pure returns (int256 result) {
    result = -x;
}


function twosComplemenBitwiseNot(int256 x) pure returns (int256 result) {
    result = ~x + 1;
}

function twosComplementAssembly(int256 x) pure returns (int256 result) {
    assembly {
        result := sub(0, x)
    }
}
```

There is no need to add 1 in the assembly implementation because subtracting from 0 is like subtracting from a virtual 2^256.

Comment: I think I'm missing something. What's wrong with `result = -result;` ?

Comment: It was me who was missing something. Thanks, @LauriPeltonen.

Answer (score 1):

In solidity the smallest value for uint256 is 0 so it can never be negative. If you want to put negative you can use int256 type which value can be -2^256 to 2^256. So you can easily implement that with int256.

eg.

```
function updateNum(int256 x) external view returns(int256){
  return -x;
}
```